# Disable Home button and Navigation bar on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-navigation, android-homebutton

Now i do Android Lockscreen app. but i cannot disable Home button and Navigation bar. I'm looking on Internet and try some solutions, but issues isn't resolve.
P.S: Lock home button for Android 5.0 - 6.0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting your first question.  For the best possible answers questions should be clear about what you are trying to achieve and what you have done to get to where you are now.  There is a [great article about how to write good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider having a read of it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want.